# Read data from a folder in main domain folder (CPanel\WHM)

Tags: htaccess

I have defined a host in my CPanel\WHM server and put all my websites under one host account. The host Main Domain is `domain.com`, and all other websites are Add-on Domains:

```
domain.com
  --folder
  --domain1
  --domain2
  --domain3
  ...
```

The thing I need is that when calling `domain.com` in browser, the server read files from another folder. for example when call `http://domain.com` it shows us `http://domain.com/folder` BUT I don't mean a redirection, I want server do this in background without showing visitors the real path.

I couldn't do this with Domain WildCard Redirection because it got error.

How can I do this? With htaccess or ... ?

Answer (score 3):

The best would be just point domain into that folder in your Control Panel.

If it is necessary to be done with **.htaccess and mod_rewrite**, then here are the rules:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/folder/
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/folder%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/folder%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule (.*) /folder/$1 [L]
```

For the above to work you need to:

- place this into **.htaccess** file in website root folder;
- have mod_rewrite enabled on your server;
- .htaccess is enabled in server config and allowed to contain rewrite rule directives (`AllowOverride All` or similar).

Consult your hosting company with the last 2 points.

Comment: Thanks, the problem solved with this But another problem made, Add-on domains and sub domains don't load now and they get "Not Found 404" error.

Comment: @Memphis Raines Please explain, I don't know how your system works. Possibly rule needs to be rewritten to accommodate this new information (depends on details you provide).

Comment: There is a CPanel\WHM Host Account. The Main Domain for this Host Account is one of my domains named domain.com , All other my domains (websites) added to this host account (Add-on domains) and the files of each one located in seperate folder. Of course the folder of the domain.com (main domain) is a level up of all them, so we have this schema: -domain.com  --folder  --website1 --website2 --website3 ...  i if someone call http://domain.com the server shows him the files located in top folder that includes other websites folder like website1, website2, ... . I create another folder here named

Comment: "folder" and i want the files of domain.com read from this folder... I can't do "WildCard Redirect" from http://[www.]domain.com to http://[www.]domain.com/folder because the CPanel show an error message. So i thought we can do samething via htaccess file rules. i need the server loading data of Domain.Com Website from a seperate folder not the top one.

Comment: @Memphis Raines See updated rule -- it will check if such file/folder does exist in `/folder/` before rewriting it. I'm still unclear on how your system works. As I understand `folder` and `domain1`, `domain2` folders are all on the same level.

Comment: Yea, All of these folders are on the same level, Some of them are the Document Root of my Add-on domains and some of them are not. The MAIN DOMAIN (domain.com) Document Root is the top level of all of them. Thanks my friend. That works properly.